# Can't find stylesheet to import with tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

how to fix

[plugin:vite:css] [sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
1 │ @import 'ui-kit/Styles/__index.scss';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\components\Background\Background.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
C:\Users\Fram Sahroni\Desktop\MyWeb\RockOrganizer\webfix\rock-organizer\src\components\Background\Background.scss:1:9

this my code :
@import 'ui-kit/Styles/__index.scss';

Can success the code